# Angular material displayWith isn't working with ngx-translate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngx-translate

I am using [displayWith] directive in my mat-autocomplete. It works fine when i am manually selecting values but when i reload the page i am not getting translation. Parameter necessary for translation is asynchronously loaded from query params in ngOnInit. So I rely on async parameter but my displayFunction() is sync function. How to resolve that?

Without [displayWith] function everything is working OK but without translation (it's just displaying pure values what i do not want). So i am sure that rest of the code is proper.

My mat-autocomplete:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="cityForm"
                appearance="outline"
                floatLabel="never"
                color="primary">
  <mat-icon matPrefix>location_on</mat-icon>
  <input type="text" placeholder="{{ 'job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.placeholder' | translate }}"
         aria-label="Number" matInput
         formControlName="cityControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event.option.value)"
                    [displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this)">
    <mat-option>
      {{ 'job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.all' | translate }}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let city of filtredCities | async" [value]="city">
      {{ 'job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.city' | translate:"{ city: '" + city +"' }"}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

My displayWith function is below:

```
displayFn(val: string){
    if (!val) return '';
    let stringToReturn;
    this.translate.get('job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.city', {city: val}).subscribe(value => {
      console.log('inside subscribe', value);
      stringToReturn = value;
    });
    console.log('after sub', stringToReturn);
    if (stringToReturn != undefined) {
      return stringToReturn;
    } else {
      return 'Sorry, value has not been translated';
    }
```

`Console.log in subscribe` is invoked after `console.log after subscribe`. So subscribe is made after i get my parameter for translation, so after my return...
I need some trick or tip to pass my translated string as a return.

I assume that there is a way to do that. Any help will be appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution of the problem was tricky. I had to use *ngIf on mat-form-field to wait for my translated label:

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="isReady$ | async" [formGroup]="cityForm"
```

Condition should be fulfilled when translation is done so I had to do this in ngOnInit:

```
 this.isReady$ = this.translate.get('translate_id').pipe(mapTo(true));
```

So now element is not beeing displayed before translation is returned from translate service. It's a workaround but I haven't found other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Observables are, at the most cases, async functions.
Depending on your implementation you may use `translate.instant`

```
displayFn(val: string) {

  const defaultMessage = 'Sorry, value has not been translated';
  return val
    ? this.translate.instant('job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.city', { city: val }) || defaultMessage
    : '';

}
```

If the instant function is called before the translation file is loaded, it will return undefined.

EDIT:

```
displayFn(val: string) {

  const translate$ = this.translate.get('job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.city', { city: val }).pipe(
    map(translatedText => translatedText || 'Sorry, value has not been translated')
  )

  return val
    ? translate$
    : of('');

}


[displayWith]="displayFn.bind(this) | async"
```

Comment: I used `translate.instant` but as i said i need parameter for translation which is loaded async :( So `translate.instant` was giving me just translation id... In this case `job_offer_search_bar.job-offer-search-bar-city-form.city`

Comment: And ur solution is returning me an empty string ' '

Comment: Try this new code I posted. Keep in mind it is not good to use the pipe async with functions neither to bind functions to properties at all.

Comment: Unfortunately now i am getting 2 errors in console now: Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'function () { [native code] }' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' and TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null. But everything compiles fine

Comment: I see, I'm sorry I running out of ideas =/

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy

you can add `AfterViewChecked` implements to your component and

on `ngAfterViewChecked` hook, add next code:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
   this._translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
       this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()
   });
}
```

In this approach, you are no needs to do something in template.

It's working for me. Enjoy.